# Vector-space invariance under normal transformation

Tags: linear-algebra

Let T be a normal transformation, $ T : \mathbb{C}^n \to \mathbb{C}^n $, and let $ 0 \neq v \in \mathbb{C}^n $. Prove that if $ \{Sp(v)\}^{\perp} $ is $T$-invariant, then $ v $ is an eigenvector of $ T$. One possible clue: Is $ T^{*}(v) \perp \{Sp(v)\}^{\perp} $ true? My guess is that because $T$ is normal then $ ImT = (ImT)^* $, but I'm not sure how to follow from there.

Comment: If $T^*(v)$ is orthogonal to $v$, then you would have $\langle T(v),v)\rangle =\langle v,T^*(v)\rangle=0$ which would mean that $T(v)$ is orthogonal to $v$.  Then $v$ could not be an eigenvector for $T$.

Comment: EDIT: The clue is an anti-clue :)

Comment: EDIT2: I've had a typo in the clue, thanks for spotting it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your updated clue is the same as asking if $v$ is an eigenvector of $T^*$, which it is:  If $x$ is orthogonal to $v$ then

$$
\langle x,T^*(v)\rangle = \langle T(x),v\rangle =0
$$

since $\operatorname{Span}(v)^\perp$ is $T$-invariant.  But that means that $T^*(v)$ is in $\left(\operatorname{Span}(v)^\perp\right)^\perp=\operatorname{Span}(v)$.  Since $T$ and $T^*$ have the same eigenvectors, you're done.